# Lua, Altered Program Flow When Rquired File isn't there

Tags: module, lua

I want to test to see if a `require`'d file is there or not.

At the present, when I execute this command in Lua:

```
require "File_That_May_or_May_Not_Be_There.inc"
```

All is well if he's there. If not, my script is dead on the spot.

Is there a way for me to recover from this ?

I looked [HERE](http://www.lua.org/pil/8.1.html) on the Lua.Org site and [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8092382/learning-lua-fast) on StackOverflow and haven't seen this answered.

Is there a way to do something like this ?...

```
if (this_exists("That_File")) then
    require "That_File"
else
    print "Your file does not exist"
end
```

I'm trying to let the user have a little better idea of what went wrong, and why.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [pcall](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-pcall).

```
local ok, mod = pcall(require, "That_File")
```

Comment: Works. Perfect. Thank you.  I must wait 10 minutes to give your answer the check mark.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't need to use `require`, which looks for modules in several locations, you can use

```
local f,e=loadfile(filename)
if f==nil then
  print(e)
else
  f()
end
```

Comment: Indeed, I would assume that `require` loads a necessary module, so I like that a bit more. That being said, the OP specifically mentioned `require`, so I upvoted both answers.